# Question about operator += overloading in c++

Tags: c++

After I overloading operator +=:

```
Object1& operator+=(Object2* r) 
{
        ObjVector.push_back(r);
        return *this;
};
```

and call it in another class's member function, it gives error like this:

error:invalid operands of type 'object*' and 'object*' to binary 'operator+'

Obj1 += Obj2;

error:in evaluation of 'operator+=(class1 object*, class2 object*)

Why it's calling 'operator+' instead of 'operator+='?

Comment: Your `operator+=` is only used in the case where `Obj1` is of type (or a reference to) `Object1`. The error message indicates that `Obj1` is of type `Object1 *` (note the asterisk). You are assuming - incorrectly - that pointers are implicitly converted to objects or references, so your code is forcing the compiler to look for an `operator+=()` that accepts two pointers.   You can probably shut the compiler up by doing `*Obj1 += Obj2`.  Depending on what `Obj1` actually points at (you haven't specified) the result will be either well defined (if it points at a valid object) or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your parameter for the `+` operator is a pointer, this will probably make the compiler happy:

```
Obj1 += &Obj2;
```

Or if they are pointers, then this;

```
*Obj1 += Obj2;
```

I generally discourage operator overloading on math operators unless there's actual math involved (e.g. a Complex number class).  In your case, you are appending a pointer reference to a member vector.  Consider the fact that `std::vector` itself doesn't have an overloaded `+` operator either.  Your operation creates a reference between Object1 and Object2 instead of a copy.  I would recommend you just have a method called `AppendObject`:

```
Object1 AppendObject(Object2* r) 
{
     ObjVector.push_back(r);
     return *this;
};
```

And then invoke it explicitly:

```
Obj1.AppendObject(&Obj2);
```

Comment: Too bad there's not a [concatenation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(string_functions)#Concatenation) in C++, given that `+` is recommended (by you, me, and many others) to be used in the mathematical sense.  (Ignoring Boost Spirit, for the nonce.)  And other languages that have them have a pretty wide set of operator symbols used.  No compelling consensus. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `Obj1` and `Obj2` are pointers. Change to this

```
*Obj1 += *Obj2;
```

and your overload to this

```
Object1& operator+=(const Object2& r)
```

Probably better still would be not using pointers in the first place. Beginners use pointers far too often. The very fact that your variables are called object 1 and object 2 indicates that they should not pointers. But without seeing more code it's hard to give advice on how you should be removing the pointers from your code.